# Undefined property: my_controller::$db

Tags: codeigniter

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: my_controller::$db

Filename: libraries/Session.php

Line Number: 88

Comment: You probably just forgot to extend `CI_Controller`

Comment: You should post some code. We have no way of helping you without seeing your code. What's at line 88?

Answer (score 8):

use

```
$this->load->database();
```

before all database operation. or open application/config/autoload.php and search

**$autoload['libraries'] = array();** replace that to

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session');
```